# Easily switch in and out of Nvidia Surround with 3 displays + 1 auxiliary display

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

When having just three displays, without the auxiliary display, Nvidia Surround can be enabled/disabled quite easily by using Windows+P to change projector settings (Extend being the normal mode and Computer Only being the Surround mode).

However, this does not work with the addition of the fourth display, and the behaviour of Windows+P gets really inconsistent. When Surround has been enabled in the control panel, Extend mode enables both surround displays and the auxiliary display, while Computer Only enables only the auxiliary display.

As in the title, how can I switch between the two modes as easily as possible, given I have 3 surround displays and one auxiliary display?

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is old. Just for the sake of google redirects, I want to introduce the piece of program I wrote a month ago and shared the code of it.

Please report problems if any (and I expect a lot as I didn't tested it widely)

https://github.com/falahati/NVIDIASurroundToggler

Comment: Just an update to this, Soroush has a new program to easily switch display settings called [Helios Display Management](https://github.com/falahati/HeliosDisplayManagement/releases) it's awesome and handles this perfectly.